# How to display vuex store information in a component

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm working on an e-commerce project using Vuejs and I've already retrieved some data into an array in the Vuex store so I want to display the array data in a component. I actually came across a tutorial online and I was able to display the array using "mapState(['myArray'])" in the computed section but I want to use something like this "return this.$store.state.myArray". Is there any other way other than using "mapstate" so I can be able to access and manipulate it in the getters{ } and in any component. Here's what I did:

```
//component

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  mounted(){
    console.log(this.$store.state.coins);
    this.$store.dispatch('loadCoins');
  },
  computed: mapState(['coins'])
}
</script>

//store.js
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state:{
    coins: []
  },
  actions:{
    loadCoins ({ commit }){      
       axios.get('http://localhost:80/api/coins.php')
         .then(response => response.data)
           .then(coins => {
            commit('SET_COINS', coins)
           });
    },
   },
   mutations:{
        SET_COINS (state, coins) {
          state.coins = coins
        }
   }
});
```

Comment: Yea, I've used it and it worked but I want to access the data not only display them and I don't seem to find a way to access them. That's why I'm asking if there's any other way rather than using mapGetters or mapState. Or if I can still access the data using them how can I do it?

Comment: You ***can*** get the data inside them! At any time. Just use `this.coins` in any method and you can access anything inside it. Or, better yet, specify **what do you mean** by *"access data"*? Just say what you're trying to do and what result you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks for this I could access it using this.coins

Comment: Made [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-k7vbu) for you, to show how to use `...mapGetters`. It turns out Vue wraps the array as object, so it can listen to its mutations. But it exposes the raw data in `this.coins.default`.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for this Sir